# Flot Bar Chart multiple series issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, flot

I've been using Flot charts for a short period of time and I need to display a bar chart with one or two series depending on the selection:

```
if (lC2 != 'None') {
      values = [
          { label: lC1, data: arrC1, color: cC1 },
          { label: lC2, data: arrC2, color: cC2 }
               ];
      bWidth = 0.15;
 }
 else {
      values = [{ data: arrC1, color: cC1 }];
      bWidth = 0.3;
}
```

and my function that draws the chart is:

```
function BarChartH(id, data, ticksl) {

$.plot(id, data, {
    series:{
        bars: {
            show: true,
            barWidth: bWidth,
            order: 1,
            horizontal: true    
        }
    },
    grid: {
        hoverable: true
        , align: "center"
        //,horizontal: true
    },
    legend: {
        show: true
    }
    , yaxis: { ticks: ticksl }
});
}
```

But when it needs to display both series (`lC2 != 'None'`) it appears only the second one (the bars become stacked).

The thing is that if I remove 'order:1' from the function and add the order for each data like:

```
values.push({ label: lC1, bars: { order:1 }, data: arrC1, color: cC1 });
values.push({ label: lC2, bars: { order:2 }, data: arrC2, color: cC2 });
```

OR

```
values = [
    { label: lC1, bars: { order:1 }, data: arrC1, color: cC1 },
    { label: lC2, bars: { order:2 }, data: arrC2, color: cC2 }];
```

it displays both of the series but with a lot of space between the bars and when there are many they overlap (the lC2 bar from the first Y label overlaps with the lC1 bar from the second Y label like in the attached image).

[image]

I need to get both the bars of the same Y label closer to make a difference between them, but I don't know what am I doing wrong.

**EDIT:**
Added: 
[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/714og5p3/6/)

Comment: Can you build a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) that shows the problem?

Comment: @Raidiri Edited the question and added the fiddle link.

Comment: That fiddle dowsn't show your problem. In fact, it doesn't run at all.

Comment: @Raidri Sorry for that. Edited the fiddle and now it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to use this plugin [orderBars](http://en.benjaminbuffet.com/flot/) ... check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Sherif_Ahmed/714og5p3/8/)
i used the orderBars plugin for that ... also you can increase the value of `bWidth` to decrease the space between bars.

also here is what i did:

```
var arrC1 = [[7,5], [3,4],[4,3],[6,2],[4,1]];
var arrC2 = [[2,5], [1,4],[0,3],[5,2],[4,1]];

var ticksl = [[5, "Five"], [4, "Four"], [3, "Three"], [2,"Two"], [1,"One"]];

var data = [{bars:{order:1},data: arrC1,color: 'red'}, 
        {bars:{order:2},data: arrC2,color: 'green'}];

var bWidth=0.43;

$.plot($('#Chart'), data, {
    series: {
        bars: {
            show:true,
            lineWidth: 1,
            barWidth: bWidth,
            order: 1,
            horizontal: true
        }
    },
    grid: {
        align: "center"
    },
    legend: {
        show: true
    },
    yaxis:{
        ticks: ticksl,
        autoscaleMargin: 0.8
    }
});
```